# Bash alias with Sed not working

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sed, pipe

Does anyone know why this alias isn't working?

```
alias tailsed="tailf error.log | sed -e 's/\\n/\n/g' -e 's/\\t/''/g'"
```

I've tried replacing the single quotes with doubles so that it's like:

```
alias tailsed='tailf error.log | sed -e "s/\\n/\n/g" -e "s/\\t/""/g"'
```

But the piped command still doesn't parse correctly like it does when it is run alone.

Comment: a)you should use single quotes around the sed, as in your first example, and as for the double quote, what if you do \"?  b)it's kind of cheating and too easy to be interesting but you could do something like \d22

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions remove all this quoting hell:

```
tailsed() { tailf error.log | sed -e 's/\\n/\n/g' -e 's/\\t//g'; }
```

Comment: Ah, didn't know you could add functions inside the bash_aliases file. Works great, thanks!

Comment: The bash startup scripts are just bash scripts, you can put anything there.